# AVPlayerItem duration zero only when streaming using WiFi connection, absolutely fine over cellular network

Tags: ios, xcode, streaming, avplayer, avasset

iOS 7.0.3

I am loading an mp3 from a URL, when this is done over a cellular (slower) connection all of the metadata loads correctly.

However when loading over WiFi the duration is zero every time. I have tried adding observers, waiting for readytoplay, initialising new avplayers... etc.

I have the same result every time: Everything works over cell but not wifi.

Here is a snippet of the code I am using, its pretty straightforward:

```
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: urlURL];
    NSLog(@"Asset Duration: %lld", asset.duration.value);
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    NSLog(@"Item Duration: %lld", playerItem.duration.value);

    audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    audioPlayer.currentItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(self.audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.value/self.audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale, 1);
    [timeSlider setMaximumValue:self.audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.value/self.audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale];
    if (playButton.selected == YES){
        [audioPlayer play];
        }
```

Please if anyone can help with suggestions I'd be extremely grateful, it's driving me barmy!

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue?